# MongoDB index for nested map values

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB Collection that contains documents with a nested map, similar to the following document:

```json
{
  "_id": "1"
  "accounts": {
    "account-id-1": { "email": "example1@example.com", ... },
    "account-id-2": { "email": "example2@example.com", ... },
  }
}
```

The `accounts` map contains account IDs as keys and the remaining account data as values/objects. Now I want to add an index for the `email` field of the nested object, but I can't do that by defining the fields as one would normally do for nested fields, e.g. `accounts.account-id-1.email` because the mid part (`account-id-1`) is different for each entry.

I have read about [wildcard indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-wildcard/#std-label-wildcard-index-core), but it seems to me that the index expression always ends withe the special wildcard symbol `$**`, but never has it in the middle.

My question is whether it's possible to define such an index in the following way or similarly: `accounts.$**.email`, so that only the `email` field gets indexed.

Comment: I would suggest change your data structure accounts should be an array while account I'd 1 you can store in name key in array of objects

Comment: Index can be defined on the object properties, for the object elements of an array field. Index on an array field is called as Multikey Index.

Comment: @BlackMamba, that's how I solved it, but I was curious if it was actually possible to have the index while keeping the map structure.

Comment: Hmm may be you can raise it on mongoDB forum they might have better idea on it but still from my experience with MongoDB I'll say always better to go with better DataStructure instead of depending a much on indexes.